# How to set additional text on check box see picture

Tags: android

How to add another text on checkbox see inside on red circle.
see below.
please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the picture shown is from checkbox preference,
you can learn the tutorial [Here](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=6&number=54)

if you don't want to use the preference, you can custom it

Answer (score 0):

Just put a LinearLayout with two TextViews inside of it next to a CheckBox. The following code should achieve what you are looking for.

```
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >  

                   <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/cb_MyCheckBox"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_TopText"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Top Text "
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:textSize="10dp" >
                            </TextView>

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_BottomText"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="BottomText "
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:textSize="10dp" >
                            </TextView>                             
                        </TextView>
                </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
```

You will need to adjust accordingly to get the desired look.

Comment: There should be a check underneath the up and down arrows that you have to click.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you getting it from Preference Activity. If you don't want Preference activity, you could use a custom listview.